# Changing drupal project folder breaks links

Tags: 7, navigation, configuration

I have a drupal project working in the server home directory. I want to move this from the server home directory to a subdirectory to make way for other drupal projects.

I move the whole drupal project from `www/var/html` to `www/var/html/old_project`

I change the `$base_url` in the drupal project settings to `http://localhost/old_project`

In the web browser I navigate to localhost/old_project. The home page displays but image links are broken. Links are broken to any other page I navigate to on the site. I can see that the urls are missing the .../old_project/...' part of the url.

Why is it omitting this and how can I fix it?

EDIT

Even when I access the urls directly typing in the '.../old_project/...' part I get 404 errors.

I have also tried adding `RewriteBase /old_project` in the `.htaccess` in `/sites/default/files/` and rebuilding the registry.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild theme registry. Download [Registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) module.
and apply the following command `drush @site rr`

Comment: Hi thanks, why does this need to be done? What exactly does it do?

Comment: It resets all your path and cache. Please read module documentation page

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work I still get 404s on every other page than home. I have tried RewriteBase to `/old_project` too. Any other suggestions? Many thanks.